# Kubernetes - how to wait for initContainers to complete initialization

Tags: kubernetes

I have several deployment manifest files corresponding to different pods. One of them has an `initContainer` that executes a specific job, upon which all dependent pods rely.

How can the other pods wait for this particular `initContainer` to complete its initialization successfully before starting?

Comment: There is no specific mechanism to create dependencies between *pods*. You could add an `initContainer` to your other pods that loops until the required conditions are met (e.g., the job has completed). Or you could have the job be responsible for launching the additional pods.

Comment: If I add ```initContainer``` to other pods how can I get an information about completed initialization? Can you please give some details? The second option is also not quite clear, it means I may have a pod which initiate other pods?

Comment: You can get information about Kubernetes resources or create new resources by using the Kubernetes API (either by writing code or by leveraging the `kubectl` command).